# Is a bad practice to have an object with internal state as an instance property in a React component?

Tags: reactjs

Is a bad practice to have an object with internal state as an instance property in a React component?

for example

```
class PageCacher {

    constructor(fetchMethod) {
        this.fetchMethod = fetchMethod
        this.pages = []
    }

    async getPage(page) {
        if (this.pages[page]) {
            return this.pages[page]
        } else {
            const result = await this.fetchMethod(page)
            this.pages[page] = result
            return result
        }
    }
}

class ItemList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.pageCacher = new PageCacher(props.fetchServiceMethod)
    }

    hanldeFetchPage = (page) => {
        this.pageCacher.getPage(page).then(result => {
            this.setState({items: result})
        })
    }
}
```

PageCache keeps the pages requested stored and returns the result if present if not makes the service call.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initializing pageCacher in the constructor, it will only receive the props present at time of the component mounting.

This means that if any of the props change, pageCacher will NOT receive those updated props.

[Link to docs on component constructor](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor)